# oracle: connection timeout when calling a plsql procedure from Java

Tags: oracle, plsql, connection, timeout

We have a daily batch job executing a oracle-plsql function. Actually the quartz scheduler invokes a java program which makes a call to the oracle-plsql function.  This oracle plsql function deletes data (which is more than 6 months) from 4 tables and then commits the transaction.

This batch job was running successfully in the test environment but started failing when new data was dumped to the tables which happened 2 weeks ago (The code is supposed to go into production this week). Earlier the number of rows in each table was not more than 0.1 million. But now it is 1 million in 3 tables and 2.4 million in the other table.

After running for 3 hours, we are getting a error in java (written in the log file) "...Connection reset; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection reset....". When the row-counts on the tables were checked, it was clear that no record was deleted from any of the tables.

Is it possible in oracle database, for the plsql procedure/function to be automatically terminated/killed when the connection is timed out and the invoking session is no longer active?

Thanks in advance,
Pradeep.

Answer (score 1):

The PL/SQL won't terminate *because* it is inactive, since by definition it isn't - it is still doing something. It won't be generating any network traffic back to your client though.

It appears something at the network level is causing the connection to be terminated. This could be a listener timeout, a firewall timeout, or something else. If it's consistently after three hours then it will almost certainly be a timeout configured somewhere rather than a network glitch, which would be more random (and possibly recoverable).

When the network connection is interrupted, Oracle will notice at some point and terminate the session. That will cause the PL/SQL call to be terminated, and that will cause any work it has done to be rolled back, which may take a while.

3 hours seems a long time for your deletes though even for a few million records. Perhaps you're deleting inefficiently, with individual inserts within your procedure. Which doesn't really help you of course. It might be worth pointing out that your production environment might not have whatever setting is killing your connection, or might have a shorter timeout, so even reducing the runtime might not make it bullet-proof in live. You probably need to find the source of the timeout and check the equivalent in the live env. to try to pre-empt similar problems there.